Functional equation: $f(x) + f(1/x) = 1$
Are they any rational polynomial function $f$ that satisfies this functional equation ?
$$f(x) + f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) = 1$$
$$0 < f'(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}^{+} $$
$$f:\mathbb{R}^{+} \to \left(0, \ 1\right)$$
Inspired by stereographic projection, I found only some solutions based on $\arctan$ only because it transforms the interval $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ into a limited one.
$$f_{1}(x) = \dfrac{2\arctan\left(x\right)}{\pi}$$
$$f_{2}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\arctan\left(\ln(x)\right)}{\pi}$$
Although I found these solutions with $\arctan$, I started searching other analytic functions that satisfies this equation.
For polynomials I only got this and I couldn't go further
$$f(x) = \dfrac{x^{p}+a_{p-1}x^{p-1}+\cdots + a_1 x}{x^{p}+b_{p-1}x^{p-1}+\cdots +b_1x + b_0}$$
Context:
I was looking for a projection that maps the entire plane into a limited region $D$, and that expands/compresses the regions near/far from the origin.
$$g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to D \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$$
I got inspired by the Poincaré disk model to set $D$ as a unit disk, and set $g$ only by scaling the point depending on an auxiliar function $f$
$$g(u, \ v) = f\left(\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\right)\left(\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}, \ \dfrac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\right)$$
For my objective of $f(x)$, the regions near $x$ must be expanded by the same amount as the regions around $1/x$ are compressed, then I got into this functional equation.

There is the obvious solution $f = \frac12$. Another one I found is $f = \frac{X}{X-1}$.

@Tzimmo see here (found using approach0.xyz)

Connected

Let $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ be a rational function in lowest terms (i.e. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have no common roots). It's pretty clear (and as you've determined) that $\deg p=\deg q$, so let their values be $n$. Now, consider $f\left(\frac 1x\right)=\frac{p_2(x)}{q_2(x)}$, with $p_2(x)=x^np\left(\frac 1x\right)$ and $q_2(x)=x^nq\left(\frac 1x\right)$. Note that $p_2(x)$ and $q_2(x)$ are just $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with their respective coefficients "swapped" (leading coefficient swapped with constant, etc) and with roots inverted, so $\frac{p_2(x)}{q_2(x)}$ is also in lowest terms.
For the sake of contradiction, assume $q(x)\neq kq_2(x)$ for some constant $k$. So, there exists some $(x-r)^a\mid q_2(x)$ such that if $(x-r)^b\mid q_1(x)$, then $a>b$. This means that when adding $f(x)$ and $f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ by constructing a least common denominator, the numerator of $f(x)$ is a multiple of $(x-r)^{a-b}$, but the numerator of $f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ is not. Hence, the entire numerator of $f(x)+f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ here is not a multiple of $(x-r)^{a-b}$, and therefore not a multiple of $(x-r)^a$. But since the denominator has $(x-r)^a$ as a factor, the resulting rational polynomial cannot cancel to $1$, a contradiction.
Hence $q(x)=kq_2(x)$ for some constant $k$. Let the leading coefficient of $q(x)$ be $l\neq 0$ and the constant term be $c$. Since $q_2(x)$ swaps $l$ and $c$, we must have $l=kc$ and $c=kl$, so $k=\pm 1$.
If $k=1$, then $q(x)=q_2(x)$, so $f(x)+f\left(\frac 1x\right)=\frac{p(x)+p_2(x)}{q(x)}$ cancels to $1$ iff $q(x)=p(x)+p_2(x)$.
If $k=-1$, then $q(x)=-q_2(x)$, so $f(x)+f\left(\frac 1x\right)=\frac{p(x)-p_2(x)}{q(x)}$ cancels to $1$ iff $q(x)=p(x)-p_2(x)$.
Thus, we can characterize all rational function solutions as follows:
Let $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and $q(x)=b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0$. The function $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is a solution to $f(x)+f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ iff one of the following is true:

$b_i=b_{n-i}$ and $a_i+a_{n-i}=b_i$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$
$b_i=-b_{n-i}$ and $a_i-a_{n-i}=b_i$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$

Some examples of working $f(x)$ are $\frac{x}{x+1}$, $\frac{3x^2+cx+2}{x^2-1}$ for all $c$, $\frac{6x^3-2x^2-x+4}{2x^3-x^2+x-2}$, etc.
